# Upgraded Postgresql from 9.1 to 9.4 on Ubuntu and now extensions are looking in the wrong folder

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

When I run

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
```

I get

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/uuid-ossp.control": No such file or directory
```

The extensions exist in

```
/usr/share/postgresql/9.4
```

How do I update where 9.4 looks for extensions?

NOTE: The database is running great. I am having no issues with the upgrade other than this.